# Writing null value to json file - java

Tags: java, json

I am using `json-simple` and trying to write a `null` value to a string.

I tried using this

```
JSONObject obj8 = new JSONObject();
obj8.put("_ArrayData_", null);
```

but I don't even see an output of it.

the output I wanted was something like this

```
_ArrayData_: null
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can you try  String jsonText = obj8.toString(); Or
  String jsonText = obj.toJSONString();
  System.out.print(jsonText); and share update. If you can share snippet of code will be more helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fjson%2Fsimple%253Fstate%253Dclosed) of the latest version of json-simple.

By my reading, what you are doing ought to work:

- In `JSONObject`, all of the serialization methods end up in:

  ```
   void writeJSONString(Map map, Writer out)
  ```

  which does nothing special with an entry whose value is `null`.
- In `JSONValue.writeJSONString` (which `writeJSONString` calls to format each entry value), a `null` is formatted as the characters "`null`".

I suspect that your problem is something else; e.g. you could be outputting a different `JSONObject` instance to the one you added the null entry to.  But if you still think it is here, we will require an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to understand what is happening in your code.